# JQuery UI tabs: How do I navigate directly to a tab from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

JQuery UI tabs are implemented by named anchors in an unordered list. When you hover over one of the tabs you can see this in the link shown at the foot of the browser:

```
http://mysite/product/3/#orders
```

Above would be the "orders" tab for example. JQuery obviously intercepts the click to this anchor and opens the tab instead.

However if I bookmark the link above or link to it from elsewhere in the site the page does not open on the specific tab.

In the tab initialisation block I was considering putting in some code that looks for a named anchor in the URL and, if it finds one, does an index lookup of the tabs and calls the select on it. This would mean it will still work with JS switched off.

But is there an easier/nicer/better way?

Comment: The JS tab control would not work with JS turned of since it's all js

Comment: Interesting - 1.3.2. Been meaning to upgrade for a while but I'm going by the "ain't broke don't fix it" policy. Sounds like I've got a good reason to upgrade now (though I'm not looking forward to the retest)

Comment: @Hunter - no the tabs wouldn't work but the behaviour would still be correct. If JS was switched off the link would take you to the correct part of the page.

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 or jQueryUI 1.3.2?

Comment: looks like I'm on the stable release so I'll probably stick with the coded solution, thanks though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this example [here](http://getrentwiz.com/blog/jquery-tab-select-from-url/):

```
if(document.location.hash!='') {
    //get the index from URL hash
    tabSelect = document.location.hash.substr(1,document.location.hash.length);
    $("#my-tabs").tabs('select',tabSelect-1);
}
```

Comment: perfect, I've wrapped this up in a helper function and called it from the load event of the tabs control, thanks

Comment: One thing this does not do is retain hash information between tabs. So if I got from www.page.com#1 to www.page.com#2 from within the same page it will not change the tab.

Comment: @Zach - where were you last year?

Comment: That's an odd question, what do you mean?

Comment: Look at the date from this question/answer. Over 1 year ago.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to a specific problem related to this answer. I don't think there's anything wrong with belated comments and questions considering everyone still receives notifications.

Comment: I didn't say anything was wrong with it. You could certainly add functionality to do what you're saying by snagging all anchor tags with a hash tag and manipulating the tabs accordingly.

Comment: Asked the question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934875/jquery-post-ui-tabs-not-linking-properly-with-page-anchors

Answer (score 5):

As of version 1.8 jQuery UI supports this functionality. See example here:

1. [Second tab active by default](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/default.html#tabs-2)
2. [Third tab active by default](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/default.html#tabs-3)

Comment: thanks, gone with the stable release for the time being but I'll upgrade when I can

Comment: BTW jQueryUI 1.8 is the current stable release (see section *What about jQuery UI 1.7?*).   http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/03/jquery-ui-18/

Comment: strange, they haven't updated the front page yet: Latest (1.8: jQuery 1.4+) Stable (1.7.2: jQuery 1.3+) - I'm using jquery 1.3 also so I would be upgrading both at the same time.

Comment: the links are no longer valid

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when content is loaded via AJAX.

Comment: @DamianNowak Not really sure what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

In versions of jQuery UI prior to 1.8 (not inclusive) that's pretty much the way you would have to do it.  The tab extension (AFAIK) doesn't know to switch based on which anchor it is initialized with (when the page loads) so you have to do that bit manually (in the ready event, of course).

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554951/jquery-ui-tabs-how-do-i-navigate-directly-to-a-tab-from-another-page/2555054#2555054) indicates, the new version of the tabs in jQuery UI 1.8 [supports bookmarking out of the box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Back_button_and_bookmarking).

Comment: thanks, just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything obvious. Must be a common requirement

Comment: FWIW the demo they have on the jQuery UI site seems to initialize properly on anchor.

Comment: @R0MANARMY - I suggest you add an answer saying "this works in the latest version". I could mark you up then

Answer (score 0):

I use the Session plugin to accomplish this in a custom tab class